# How to detect instantly when user closes Popup using $firebaseAuth().$signInWithPopup?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I´m implementing Google authentication signin using Firebase Authentication with angularFire service $firebaseAuth and the method $signInWithPopup.

The method returns a promise if it's resolved or rejected, to this point all clear.

What I´m trying to improve is when a user closes the popup window without signing in.
In this case, the code error returned by the promise is: `auth/popup-closed-by-user`.
The problem is that this **can take up to 30 seconds to happen**:

```
app.controller("SampleCtrl", function($firebaseAuth) {

  $firebaseAuth().$signInWithPopup("google").then(function(result) {
    console.log("Signed in as:", result.user.uid);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
  });

});
```

Is there a way to catch instantly when the popup is closed?

---

EDIT: I´m using `angularFire 2.0.1` and `Firebase 3.0.3`

Comment: Using  `angularfire 1.2.0` this delay is not happening so I suppose that this is a `firebase 2.0.1` issue.

Comment: thanks for pointing out @adolfosrs , in fact I´m using `angularFire 2.0.1` and `Firebase 3.0.3`

Comment: I'm having the same issue using the only the firebase library version 3.1.0

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer 5 years later

Comment: using "firebase": "^9.1.2", you have to wait for "auth/popup-closed-by-user" only 2 sec so I believe there is no issue here. :)